# How to get 7D-retention from a given date for a given user in SQL (Redshift)?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table with user-date data. I want to understand if a user returned to the app within 7 days of the current date (of that row). And if so, I want to simply return a 1 else 0. Here is an example:

```
date        | user_id | 7D-retention
2022-10-01  | 1       | 1 (because 2022-10-01 + 7 days = 2022-10-08 and user returned at least another time on/before 2022-10-08 which was on 2022-10-05)
2022-10-05  | 1       | 0 (because 2022-10-05 + 7 days = 2022-10-12 and user did not at least another time on/before 2022-10-12)
2022-12-01  | 2 ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this, using LEAD analytic function..

```
SELECT "date", "user_id",
       CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, "date", LEAD("date", 1) OVER (PARTITION BY "user_id" ORDER BY "date")) < 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS retention_7d
FROM mytable
ORDER BY "user_id", "date"
```